# 'PRIMARY' Error where there isn't any duplicated PRIMARY Key

Tags: mysql

I was using this code

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_TABLE AS SELECT * FROM LOG_COLUMN_INFO WHERE STID = 0 AND NAME = 'Comments';
UPDATE TEMP_TABLE SET STID = (SELECT @SID);
UPDATE TEMP_TABLE SET COLUMNID = (SELECT MAX(COLUMNID)+1 FROM LOG_COLUMN_INFO);
INSERT INTO LOG_COLUMN_INFO SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM 
LOG_COLUMN_INFO WHERE STID = (SELECT @SID) AND NAME = 'Comments' LIMIT 1);
DROP TABLE TEMP_TABLE;
```

And it gives me

```
1062 - Duplicate entry '766' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I know that `COLUMNID` is set as `PRIMARY` so I made it not to be duplicated. And actually there isn't any value of 766 in `COLUMNID` in exsisting table.

Also, when I use the same code only changed `NAME` like this

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_TABLE AS SELECT * FROM LOG_COLUMN_INFO WHERE STID = 0 AND NAME = 'Result';
UPDATE TEMP_TABLE SET STID = (SELECT @SID);
UPDATE TEMP_TABLE SET COLUMNID = (SELECT MAX(COLUMNID)+1 FROM LOG_COLUMN_INFO);
INSERT INTO LOG_COLUMN_INFO SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM 
LOG_COLUMN_INFO WHERE STID = (SELECT @SID) AND NAME = 'Result' LIMIT 1);
DROP TABLE TEMP_TABLE;
```

Then it worked. And if I do `NAME = Comments` again, it gives the error with just changing the value from 766 to increased one.

Anyone has any assumption why this is happening?

Comment: How many rows do you have in your temp table (e.g. how many comments with stid = 0 in your log table)? If more than one, then you update all of those with the same columnid - which you cannot insert back into the log table with that columnid.

Comment: @Solarflare Yeah that was my first and current assumption since there are some multiple comments with stid = 22 etc. But, with stid=0, it only have 1 row with Name filed of Comments . So it's still sus, but I can't pick up the issue about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
UPDATE TEMP_TABLE SET COLUMNID = (SELECT MAX(COLUMNID)+1 FROM LOG_COLUMN_INFO);
```

sets all the rows to have the same value.  So your insert to LOG_COLUMN_INFO will fail on the second row.

I suggest you explicitly create the temp table and make an autoincrementing primary key starting with 1 (and then only select all the *other* columns from LOG_COLUMN_INFO when you do your insert into TEMP_TABLE).  And then do:

```
update TEMP_TABLE set COLUMNID=COLUMNID + (SELECT MAX(COLUMNID)+1 FROM LOG_COLUMN_INFO) order by COLUMNID desc;
```

Comment: Brilliant. I forgot that I filtered it at first place, so there were other rows with same NAME. the result of your code reminded me. Thanks!